# How do I convert text files in bash? (foo.txt to bar.txt)

Tags: linux, bash, text, encoding, newline

I'm trying to append, via bash, one text file to another using `foo.txt >> bar.txt`. The problem is, foo.txt is a windows text file (I think), because once appended in bar.txt

```
every new^M
line^M
ends^M
like this.^M
```

Thus, they are surely two different file-types.

I've searched Google for answers but [Google doesn't accept special characters like ">>" and "^" in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters). The closest solution I can find is [a reported solution on commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9224/convert-windows-text-file-to-linux-text-document), but all it does is strip the r's from bar.txt which, really, is no solution at all.

So, I have two questions here:

1. How do I discover, using bash, what file-type foo.txt really is?
2. How do *convert* foo.txt properly to make it appendable to bar.txt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" foo.txt >> bar.txt
```

or use `dos2unix`, if it's available.

Comment: How do I determine it is a dos file before attempting to convert it?

Comment: view it in vi? If there's ^M chars at the end of the line, it's in dos format.  or if you're in Windows, load the file into notepad. If you have no line breaks at all, it's unix format.

Comment: The `sed` command is safe to use even if there are no carriage returns (^M).

Comment: I'll come back and vote you up for offering the sed solution, Marc (when I can up-vote, I mean). I was definitely looking for a native solution first, but now that I know the answer to both questions I'll probably be using the dos2unix approach. Much appreciated.

Comment: @trench you can use the `file` command to tell the format of the file before converting. However, using `dos2unix` on a file thats already in unix format is harmless.

Comment: Thanks, @tMC, but I was looking for a command that would perform a test on the file. `file` is definitely my solution there.

dos2unix is working great though. 

@Marc B, could you edit your answer to include @Christopher Foy's `file foo.txt` answer as well? And maybe upvote him? Because that definitely answered my first question... you answered the second question. thanks. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: Also, of note: When viewed in vim and vi, the ^M characters are not visible in the dos file. Another reason the `file foo.txt` answer needs some upvote love.

Comment: @Marc: vi (at least `vim`) recognizes DOS-format text files and doesn't display the trailing `^M`s.  But it does show `[dos]` on the status line.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the Windows line endings with `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix foo.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `file foo.txt` will output: "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" if the file has DOS-style line endings.

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the remaining answer I was looking for.

Comment: If it's just plain text, yes.  But for some recognized types of files, the `file` command doesn't show you how it's encoded.  For example, `file tmp.html` prints `tmp.html: HTML document text`, regardless of the encoding (at least the Ubuntu version of the `file` command does this).

Comment: file --mime-encoding foo.html will output us-ascii, utf-8 &c.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fromdos` and `todos`, or `unix2dos` and `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the commands `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`. You may wish to make a copy first (`cp`)

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution:

```
tr -d '\r' < foo.txt
```